# Using graphics.drawimage method in c#

Tags: c#, drawing

Though I have experience in C, I'm totally new to Object oriented programming, so, if it's not too much to ask, I'd like you to help me at giving me just 1 example of using this method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142040(v=vs.110).aspx in C#. Its not for homework, since I'm an enthusiastic programmer, what happens is that I learn by example, and I want an example of this:

A form that has 1 button which when pressed shows 1 image - could be a bmp or anything - I would really appreciate your help.

I also learned C for programming micro controllers by reading examples, not by understanding theory.

Comment: So what's your question? An example for `Graphics.DrawImage()`, or an example of the form with one button that shows an image?

Comment: an example of a form with one buttong that shows an image using the graphics.drawimage(), thanks

Comment: lol, no, it's not, i know it sounds like one, but it's not, im not a software engineer, but an electronic engineer,graduated, but i don't have a teacher to "teach me" programming, and i learn by example, i came with this problem because i only programmed c, using a graphical interface is totally new to me and loading an image is a very atractive thing to do, well, it's up to you to believe me, thanks for taking your time and reading it.

Comment: ok thanks, any help will be apreciated, i know that anybody can be "anybody" on internet, but im telling the truth, the proof is that i will use your help and show the image :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to give you a complete code-on-a-platter direct answer, but here is a way to hopefully get you started. Try using the `Button_Click` event handler and `this.CreateGraphics()`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\X\Pictures\CAROLINAPANTHERS.png");
    Graphics x = this.CreateGraphics();
    x.DrawImage(image,new Rectangle(0,0,image.Width, image.Height), ...);
}
```

LMK if this helps.

Comment: Aww yeah, thanks it worked as a charm, correct me if im wrong..you used the Graphics x = this.CreateGraphics(); to create an object of class graphics?? and what is this?? i had understood from before that it "points to the object" being used right?

Comment: @NelsonRios this refers to the Class, in this case the Form. The CreateGraphics method gives you access to the drawing surface of the Form which you then can use to draw your images. Since you are creating it explicitly you need to make sure to dispose of it also. another caution is that as soon as  your form is refreshed your drawings will disappear, most drawing code is better of put into the Paint EventHandler where it will be redrawn upon a refresh.

Comment: Thank @MarkHall, I didn't see that edit he made to his comment.